# Inner join limit the rows from second table

Tags: mysql, sql

There are 2 tables `queries` and `transactions`, 1 transaction can have multiple queries. I want to fetch the list of queries for 10 transactions. I tried this query but this is limiting total row count.

```
SELECT t.tid
     , q.id
     , q.timestamp
     , q.domain
     , q.health
     , q.alexa_rank
     , q.destination
     , t.age
     , t.sb_isValid
     , t.userResponse
     , t.suggestion 
  from queries q 
  join transactions t 
    on q.id like concat(t.tid, '%') 
 where t.uid = '115800979895438175088' 
 order 
    by t.time DESC
     , tid 
 limit 10
```

This query is returning 10 rows including queries and transactions, but I want 10 transactions with its queries.

If there are 10 transactions and each has 3 queries then it should return 30+10 = 40 rows but it is returning 10 rows only.

Comment: Which transactions do you want? The ten transactions that had the most recent queries?

Comment: On a sidenote: It's a very bad data design not to have the two tables linked by proper foreign keys, but to rely on a substring instead. Change this if you can.

Comment: Which MySQL version are you running?

Comment: I want to fetch the last 10 transactions with their queries, Thank you for your suggestion but now it is too late to make any changes in tables.

Comment: And the "last" transactions are those with the most recent queries? Or the ones with the highest IDs? The ones with the lowest t.age? Or which else?

Comment: Last 10 transactions ordered by timestamp `t.time`

Comment: "too late to make any changes" usually means "we are running this system only for a few weeks more, so it would not be worth it to make changes now". This would sound like a good decision to me. If it means "we are going to run this system for a long time to come, but making changes would feel so inconvenient, and we'll rather continue running the system slow and error-prone", this would sound like a bad decision.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion I will immediately take action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the ten transactions in a subquery:

```
select *
from
(
  select *
  from transactions
  order by time desc
  limit 10
) t
join queries q on q.id like concat(t.tid, '%')
order by t.time desc, t.tid, q.timestamp desc;
```

Comment: It worked but the result is not in descending order

Comment: Then change the `ORDER BY` clause. (I've also updated my answer accordingly. `t.time` was not in your original request, so I made up an appropriate `ORDER BY` clause.)